# Structured Streaming + UDF - logic based on checking if a column is present in the Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using StructuredStreaming, and am trying to use UDF to parse each row.
Here is the requirement:

- we can get alerts of a particular KPI with type 'major' OR 'critical'
- for a KPI, if we get alerts of type 'major' eg _major, and we have a critical alert as well _critical, we need to ignore the _major alert, and consider _critical alert only

There are ~25 alerts which are stored in the array (AlarmKeys.alarm_all)

Below is the (draft)code which i'm using.

```
@udf(returnType=StringType())
def convertStructToStr(APP_CAUSE, tenantName, window,<one>,<two>__major,<three>__major, <four>__critical, five__major, <six>__critical):

    res = "{window: "+ str(window) + "type: 10m, applianceName: "+ str(APP_CAUSE)+","
    first = True
    for curr_alarm in AlarmKeys.alarms_all:
        alsplit = curr_alarm.split('__')
        if len(alsplit) == 2:
            # Only account for critical row if both are there
            if alsplit[1] == 'major':
                critical_alarm = alsplit[0] + "__critical"
                if int(col(critical_alarm)) > 0:
                    continue
        if int(col(curr_alarm)) > 0:
            if first:
                mystring = "{} {}({})".format(mystring, AlarmKeys.alarm_exp[curr_alarm], str(col(curr_alarm)))
                first = False
            else:
                mystring = "{}, {}({})".format(mystring, AlarmKeys.alarm_exp[curr_alarm], str(col(curr_alarm)))
        res+="insight: "+mystring +"}"


# structured streaming using udf, this is printing data on console
# eventually, i'll put data into Kafka instead
df.select(convertStructToStr(*df.columns)) \
.write \
    .format("console") \
    .option("numRows",100)\
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/Users/karanalang/PycharmProjects/Kafka/checkpoint") \
    .option("outputMode", "complete")\
    .save("output")
```

Question is - can this be done using UDF ?
Since i'm passing column values to the UDF, i have no way to check if a particular KPI of type 'critical' is available in the dataframe ?

What is the best way to solve this kind of a problem ?

Pls note : the original code uses (DStreams+)Pandas and KafkaProducer .. which loops over all the rows of the dataframe and creates a json string.Then KafkaProducer is used to push data into Kafka.
I'm trying to convert this to use StructuredStreaming(Apache Spark v3.1.2), if possible.

tia!

Clarification(based on comment from @OneCricketeer :

- <> just represents a placeholder,
- An example of the KPI would be 'cpu_utilization__critical' and 'cpu_utilization__major'.
  if both have values, i want to report only the critical alert i.e. 'cpu_utilization__critical',
  so in the map, i would add entry -> insights="High CPU utilization(cpu_utilization__critical),
  where High CPU utilization -> description of the alert, cpu_utilization__critical -> actual KPI

Comment: What are these `<>` arguments? That is not valid Python. What is currently being written to the console? Can you give examples of your input and expected output?

Comment: @OneCricketeer - <> just represents a placeholder, an example of the KPI would be 'cpu_utilization__critical' and 'cpu_utilization__major'. if both have values, i want to report only the critical alert i.e. 'cpu_utilization__critical', so in the map -> insights="High CPU utilization(cpu_utilization__critical), where High CPU utilization -> description of the alert,  cpu_utilization__critical -> actual KPI

Comment: So, in the UDF, it's just a Python function, so you can give `*args` as the parameter rather than list them all out. But I think it's also possible to make sure that's just one parameter Row object somehow

Comment: thnx, let me check on this